# Reading excel/CSV into python

Tags: python, dataframe, import, valueerror

Running the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df1=pd.read_csv("/Users/ee1.xlsx")
```

Getting an error back as

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Going out of my mind to trying to resolve this. I'm running Spyder python 2.7 in Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

you have to open excel file using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel("/Users/ee1.xlsx")
```

Excel files and csv files are different.